# Is php://temp safe for production?

Tags: php, thread-safety

I have a scenario in which I want to re-use an existing class to compile changes in the system. The existing libraries take a file pointer that will store the changes for subsequent use. The current scenario involves performing those calculations and then immediately outputting the response to output.

Would it be safe to use the php://temp or php://memory resources in an environment where it is possible that two separate users will run this method at the same time?

Pseudo-code:

```
$fp = fopen('php://temp','w+');
Lib::getUpdates($fp, $user_id);
rewind($fp);
$changes = stream_get_contents($fp);
```

I have been googling around and have found some unsettling results but nothing really definitive about using the temp or memory streams.

So the question is, should I just break down and use a temporary file that will guarantee this isn't a problem? I would like to avoid writing to disk if possible. The other possibility is to alter the class so that it can output the results to a string, but I'd like to avoid that if possible as well.

EDIT

According to Sammitch, this is ok. See comments below.

Comment: `php://temp` and `php://memory` are unique per-process. You do not have to worry about two processes attempting to use the same memory at the same time.

Comment: I think `php://temp` will transparently use a temporary file in some situations anyway

Comment: Small question though, if php://temp or php://memory are per-process, arent those in effect the same as using a plain old global variable? And is it not better to just use a more elaborate object/storage class as global variables are bad code? I dont want to criticise your code, just wondering what reasons you have for this solution?

Comment: @ToBe - if you are limited by available memory then sometimes it makes sense to put your intermediary data to a file. php://temp makes it easy since you do not have to care about location, file name, permissions, etc. It will also try to stick to memory until it reaches (usually) 2MB limit. In case of variable you will have "nowhere to go" once you hit php's memory limit.

Comment: @ToBe I guess it would be similar to having a global variable and normally I would use some kind of storage class. I this scenario, however, I needed to pass a file into the method which was supposed to get the data. This solution was going to be a temporary hack that would allow me to emulate a file resource until I had time to refactor (it needed to be done for a demo today). In the end, it doesn't matter because it turns out that I had anticipated this issue and built in alternate methods to get this data.

Comment: Tnx for the info. I'll definetly keep this in mind. Especially when working with streams and/or in situations like yours.

Comment: You (or Sammitch) might want to copy the comment into an answer so that this question can be closed correctly.

Comment: @Sammitch can you copy the answer over?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`php://temp` and `php://memory` are unique per-process. You do not have to worry about two processes attempting to use the same memory at the same time.